# Next.js / graphql / apollo-server-micro => API resolved without sending a response for /api/graphql, this may result in stalled request

Tags: next.js, graphql, apollo-server

I am trying to start a project with next.js, graphql and apollo-server-micro.

But I got an error when I am running `localhost:3000/api/graphql` and I don't know how to solve it.

Playground is launching as expected, and when I am clicking on 'Query your server', I got this error.

```bash
npm run dev                                                                                                                                                                               

> next-graphql@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
info  - SWC minify release candidate enabled. https://nextjs.link/swcmin
event - compiled client and server successfully in 421 ms (177 modules)
wait  - compiling /api/graphql...
event - compiled successfully in 54 ms (49 modules)
MongoDB connected 
error - Error: called start() with surprising state started
    at ApolloServer._start (/home/floslv/Flo/Dev/Learning/next-graphql/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/ApolloServer.js:185:19)
    at ApolloServer.start (/home/floslv/Flo/Dev/Learning/next-graphql/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/ApolloServer.js:180:27)
    at handler (webpack-internal:///(api)/./pages/api/graphql.js:30:24)
    at Object.apiResolver (/home/floslv/Flo/Dev/Learning/next-graphql/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils/node.js:184:15)
    at DevServer.runApi (/home/floslv/Flo/Dev/Learning/next-graphql/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:381:27)
    at async Object.fn (/home/floslv/Flo/Dev/Learning/next-graphql/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:491:37)
    at async Router.execute (/home/floslv/Flo/Dev/Learning/next-graphql/node_modules/next/dist/server/router.js:213:36)
    at async DevServer.run (/home/floslv/Flo/Dev/Learning/next-graphql/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:610:29)
    at async DevServer.run (/home/floslv/Flo/Dev/Learning/next-graphql/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:532:20)
    at async DevServer.handleRequest (/home/floslv/Flo/Dev/Learning/next-graphql/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:311:20) {
  page: '/api/graphql'
}
wait  - compiling /_error (client and server)...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 108 ms (196 modules)
MongoDB connected 
API resolved without sending a response for /api/graphql, this may result in stalled requests.
error - Error: called start() with surprising state started
    at ApolloServer._start (/home/floslv/Flo/Dev/Learning/next-graphql/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/ApolloServer.js:185:19)
    at ApolloServer.start (/home/floslv/Flo/Dev/Learning/next-graphql/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/ApolloServer.js:180:27)
    at handler (webpack-internal:///(api)/./pages/api/graphql.js:30:24)
    at Object.apiResolver (/home/floslv/Flo/Dev/Learning/next-graphql/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils/node.js:184:15)
    at DevServer.runApi (/home/floslv/Flo/Dev/Learning/next-graphql/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:381:27)
    at async Object.fn (/home/floslv/Flo/Dev/Learning/next-graphql/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:491:37)
    at async Router.execute (/home/floslv/Flo/Dev/Learning/next-graphql/node_modules/next/dist/server/router.js:213:36)
    at async DevServer.run (/home/floslv/Flo/Dev/Learning/next-graphql/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:610:29)
    at async DevServer.run (/home/floslv/Flo/Dev/Learning/next-graphql/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:532:20)
    at async DevServer.handleRequest (/home/floslv/Flo/Dev/Learning/next-graphql/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:311:20) {
  page: '/api/graphql'
}
```

Here is my `package.json` :

```json
{
  "name": "next-graphql",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.6.9",
    "apollo-server-micro": "^3.10.0",
    "graphql": "^16.5.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.5.1",
    "next": "12.2.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.21.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.2.4"
  }
}
```

Here is my `pages/api/graphql.js` :

```js
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-micro';

import typeDefs from '../../backend/graphql/typeDefs.js';
import resolvers from '../../backend/graphql/resolvers/index.js';

import connectDb from '../../backend/db/config/connectDb.js';

// Connection to DB
connectDb();

// Graphql
const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
        typeDefs,
        resolvers
});

// Next config
export const config = {
        api: {
                bodyParser: Boolean(false),
        }
};

// Run server
const handler = async (req, res) => {
        await apolloServer.start();
        apolloServer.createHandler({ path: '/api/graphql' })(req, res);
};

export default handler;
```

Is anyone knows what I am doing wrong ?

I think it's inside my handler function, but I don't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I did wrong, just need to keep `apolloServer.start()` in a variable before called `createHandler`

```bash
const startServer = apolloServer.start();

// Run server
const handler = async (req, res) => {
        await startServer;
        apolloServer.createHandler({ path: '/api/graphql' })(req, res);
};
```